# Use both autoclear and preserveDrawingBuffer in WebGLrenderer

Tags: three.js, webgl, renderer, orbit, todataurl

I have a Three.js scene, where I have set renderer's preserveDrawingBuffer:true because I want to use renderer.toDataURL to take a snapshot of what is on the canvas, and I also use renderer.autoClear = false because I am using 2 scenes with one camera each (one renderer of course).

The problem is that when I move the camera with orbitControls, the objects do not animate as they should, their previous states stay on the canvas and they are creating an ugly painting ( they are not erased) because of the preserveDrawingBuffer:true setting.

What can I do to have both the snapshot functionality the 2 scenes/cameras and the orbit controls?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a simple fiddle to demonstrate the issue? Here is a start: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/

Comment: here is the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/17/

Comment: Your example has an empty scene and no snapshot.

Comment: I am adding them right now...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/18/  the link to download image is at the bottom of the canvas.

Comment: `SceneOrtho` is empty. `crcl` is not used. The shapshot or link does not show...

Comment: it doesn't matter that the crcl is not used, it is not the problem. the snapshot link is located down at the bottom ( zoom out your browser). you will see it if you scroll down. the problem is how to have preserveDrawingBuffer:true and renderer.autoClear = false and when I move the camera everything to be normal.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/19/ now everything you said is there.

Comment: Yes it does matter. You need 2 scenes, each with content, and properly-positioned cameras. You did not have that. Now you have a light with an invalid position. I want to make sure that what I propose does not break anything that is currently working. So far, you do not have a working demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/20/ I hope now is ok. I think before it also was working. if it is not right now, then just tell me your solution please. thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. I have to figure out a solution, and I need your use case first.

Comment: come on man, what is wrong with my scene now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are instantiating `WebGLRenderer` and preserving the drawing buffer like so:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { preserveDrawingBuffer: true } );
```

And if you are setting

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
```

you will have to call `renderer.clear()` before rendering like so:

```
renderer.clear();
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

three.js r.69

Comment: All told, I spent 1.5 hours on your issue. I think you are missing the point.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, and I understand that your point is to present a good description of our problem and you are right.

Comment: That "not a big deal" comment is shocking!